# How to rename variables in a loop in Python

Tags: python, variables, loops

I want to run a program in Python which loops several times, creating a NEW array each time - i.e. no data is overwritten - with the array named with a reference to the loop number, so that I can call it in subsequent loops. For instance, I might want to create arrays x0, x1, x2, ..., xi in a loop running from 0 to i, and then call each of these in another loop running over the same variables. (Essentially the equivalent of being able to put a variable into a string as `'string %d %(x)'`).

Comment: The best way is not to do this... use a list (or dictionary) instead

Comment: Your problem is that you are using local variables where you should be using a list or dictionary *instead*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a dict:

```
arraysDict = {}
for i in range(0,3):
    arraysDict['x{0}'.format(i)] = [1,2,3]

print arraysDict
# {'x2': [1, 2, 3], 'x0': [1, 2, 3], 'x1': [1, 2, 3]}
print arraysDict['x1']
# [1,2,3]
```

Using a list:

```
arraysList = []
for i in range(0,3):
    arraysList.append([1,2,3])

print arraysList
# [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
print arraysList[1]
# [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can access the `globals()` dictionary to introduce new variables. Like:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    globals()['x'+str(i)] = i
```

After this loop you get

```
>>> x0, x1, x2, x3, x4
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Note, that according to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals), you should not use the `locals()` dictionary, as changes to this one *may not affect the values used by the interpreter*.

Comment: Except that it doesn't work for `locals()`

Comment: Yes, I already changed my answer. Although it seems to work, if you only introduce new variables (and don't change their value afterwards)

Comment: Note to anyone reading this answer : PLEASE DONT DO SUCH A STUPID THING. The correct solution is to use a dict or list.

Comment: I didn't suggest that this is a good way to do anything. But I believe it is a correct answer to a perfectly valid original question. Perhaps you might want to reread the SO section on downvoting ...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers There are a couple of scenarios where it might make sense to modify the global environment (there might be a reason for the presence of the `globals()` dict after all...) Without knowing anything more, you cannot say, if this is the case here.

Answer (score 2):

Relying on variables's names and changing them is not the best way to go.

As people already pointed out in comments, it would be better to use a dict or a list instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object for this, and then use the [setattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) function for this.
Basically, it will work like this:

```
setattr(myobject, 'string', value)
```

It is the same as doing : `myobject.string = value`